# When and by whom was the rule for using 'compare to' versus 'compare with' first recorded?

Tags: etymology, history, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs, is-it-a-rule

A longstanding question on English Language & Usage asks ["Compared with" vs "Compared to"—which is used when?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/583/compared-with-vs-compared-to-which-is-used-when) and has drawn several useful answers. But the question doesn’t invite answers to questions about the origin of the rule itself.

*Webster's Dictionary of English Usage* (1989) dedicates more than two full pages to a discussion of *compare to* versus *compare with*. In the course of its discussion, WDEU cites a letter written by Theodore Bernstein to the editor of *Word Study* in 1947, asserting that the rule about when to use *compare with* and when to use *compare to*  first appeared in Webster's *American Dictionary of the English Language* (1847). Here is the 1847 Webster's dictionary's entry for *compare* as a verb:

> COMPARE, *v. t.*  ...
>
> **1.** To set or bring things together in fact or in contemplation, and to examine the relations they bear to each other, with a view to ascertain their agreement or disagreement ; as, to *compare* two pieces of cloth, two tables, or coins ; to *compare* reasons and arguments ; to *compare* pleasure *with* pain.
>
> In comparing movable things, it is customary to bring them together, for examination. In comparing things immovable or remote, and abstract ideas, we bring them together in the mind, as far as we are able, and consider them in connection. Comparison therefore is really collation, or it includes it.
>
> **2.** To liken ; to represent as similar, for the purpose of illustration.
>
> > Solon *compared* the people *to* the sea, and orators and counsellors *to* the winds ; for that the sea would be calm and quiet, if the winds did not trouble it. *Bacon.*
>
> In this sense *compare* is followed by *to*.
>
> **3.** To examine the relations of things to each other, with a view to discover their relative proportions, quantities, or qualities ; as, to *compare* two kingdoms, or two mountains, *with* each other ; to *compare* the number ten *with* fifteen ; to *compare* ice *with* crystal ; to *compare* a clown *with* a dancing-master or a dandy.
>
> In this sense *compare* is followed by *with*.

*WDEU* focuses its attention on twentieth-century usage, so it doesn’t reach any conclusion about whether the rule spelled out by Webster's 1847 dictionary reflected actual practice or only the preferences of Noah Webster. It concludes that current (in 1989) practice in English is (on the one hand) to use *compare to* "more often than not" when the sense of the active verb is "liken" but (on the other) to use *compared to* and *compared with* "about equally after the past participle" when the sense of the verb is "examined so as to discover the resemblances and differences."

Without getting too caught up in the side issue of whether common usage ever definitively supported the rule that appears in Webster’s 1847 dictionary, I would like to know two things:

> 1. When was the rule about when to use *compared to* and when to use *compared with* first set down in a published work?
> 2. Who was the author of that first statement of the rule?

Comment: Don't forget there's also [comparing apples **to** oranges](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/132871/origin-of-comparing-apples-and-oranges/380907#380907)

Answer (score 3):

Although Theodore Bernstein was certainly correct in asserting that *An American  Dictionary of the English Language* (1847) offers a fairly elaborate exposition of the rule in question, he was not correct in suggesting that Webster first offered this exposition in 1847. The very same language appears in the entry for the verb *compare* in the first version of Webster's full-scale dictionary, [*An American Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BF9fAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP453&dq=%22set+or+bring+things+together+in+fact+or+in+contemplation%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0p7jtzbfTAhVQ0WMKHYttAE8Q6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22set%20or%20bring%20things%20together%20in%20fact%20or%20in%20contemplation%22&f=false) (1828).

So any prior statement of Webster’s rule must beat that date, not 1847. In early editions of Samuel Johnson, [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.com/books?id=fcVEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT428&dq=%22heart+string%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAGoVChMI0efv_oKqyAIVkTaICh0v5wLu#v=onepage&q=%22compare%20v.%20a.%22&f=false) (1756), there is no discussion of what preposition should follow *compare* in different situations:

> To COMPARE. *v. a.* {*comparo*, Lat.} **1.** To make one thing the measure of another ; to estimate the relative goodness or badness. [Example: "No man can think it grievous who considers the pleasure and sweetness of love, and the glorious victory of overcoming evil with good ; and then compares  these with the restless torment, and perpetual tumults, of a malicious and revengeful spirit."] *Tillotson.* **2.** To get ; to procure ; to obtain. *Spenser*.

It isn't as though Johnson had no interest in the different meanings that may arise from combining a verb with different prepositions. For example, his 1756 dictionary's entry for *come* includes 39 separate numbered definitions for combinations of *come* and a following preposition or adverb (*come about*, *come at*, *come by*, *come in*, *come in for*, *come in to*, and so on). But he says nothing about *compare to* and *compare with*.

In fact, rather strikingly, Johnson doesn't mention the "liken" sense of *compare* at all, and neither do subsequent editions of his dictionary through at least 1778. Webster does refer to it in his [*Compendious Dictionary of the English Language*](http://www.premierathome.com/Library/Reference/Webster%27s%201806%20Dictionary.txt) (1806), but not with any distinction in preposition use:

> Compare, *v. t.* to liken, examin to find agreement  or disagreement ; in the sense of procure *ob[solete]*

In any event, Webster wasn't the first lexicographer to refer to the "liken" sense of *compare*. John Kersey, [*Dictionarium Anglo-Britannicum: or, A General English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=t01gAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT504&dq=%22full+Moon+which+comes+before+any+great+moveable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMI_YvMm8_YxgIVBouSCh1Ungh4#v=onepage&q=%22examine%20one%20thing%20by%20another%22&f=false) (1708) has this:

> To **Compare**, to examine one thing by another, to liken.

To similar effect, a century later, William Perry's revision of Johnson's dictionary, titled [*The Synonymous, Etymological, and Pronouncing English Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=JSdoAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT106&dq=%22make+one+thing+the+measure+of+another+;+to+estimate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjTlJjIu7bTAhWJslQKHXa3DHQ4FBDoAQgoMAE#v=onepage&q=%22make%20one%20thing%20the%20measure%20of%20another%20%3B%20to%20estimate%22&f=false) (1805), has this entry:

> COMPARE, (Lat *comparo*) to make one thing the measure of another, to estimate the relative goodness or badness, or other qualities, of any one thing, by observing how it differs from something else, to liken, resemble, confer (Boyle), confront (Addison) ; to parallel, to paragon ; *with* to *and* with.

The first dictionary to notes explicitly that *compare* may be used with *to* and *with*, however, may be John Ash, [*The New and Complete Dictionary of the English Language*](https://books.google.it/books?id=m_1IAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT169&dq=%22COMPARE%20(v.%20t.%20from%20the%20Lat.%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22COMPARE%20(v.%20t.%20from%20the%20Lat.%22&f=true) (1775), which has this:

> COMPARE (*v. t. from the* Lat. con *with, and* paro *to make*) To make one thing the measure of another ; *with* to *and* with : as, "*He* compared *anger* to *fire*," "*He* compares *the translation* with *the original*."

But neither Ash nor Perry argues that there is properly no overlap in usage between *compare to* and *compare with*.

Returning to Noah Webster, it appears that his dictionary was not the first to cite the example from Bacon either, nor was it the first to make a serious attempt to distinguish between the meanings of *compare to* and *compare with*. In [H.J. Todd's edition of Johnson's *Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=SAxaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT726&dq=%22make+one+thing+the+measure+of+another+;+to+estimate%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL_IfmsLbTAhVU5mMKHc4GBT44ChDoAQgiMAA#v=onepage&q=%22make%20one%20thing%20the%20measure%20of%20another%20%3B%20to%20estimate%22&f=false) (1818), we find the Bacon quotation, a definition devoted to coverage of the "liken" sense of *compare*, and separate meanings that properly take *to* and *with*:

> To COMPARE. *v. a.* {*comparo*, Lat.}
>
> **1.** To make one thing the measure of another ; to estimate the relative goodness or badness, or other qualities of any one thing, by observing how it differs from something else. [Examples omitted.]
>
> **2.** It may be observed, that when the comparison intends only similitude or illustration by likeness, we use *to* before the thing brought for illustration ; as, he *compared* anger *to* a fire. [Bacon example omitted.]
>
> **3.** When two persons or things are compared, to discover their relative proportion of any quality, *with* is used before the thing used as a measure. [Examples omitted.]

So the chronology looks like this:

> **1708** Kersey's *Dictionarium Anglo-Britannicum* records the “examine one thing by another” (effectively, "examine side by side") and "liken" meanings of *compare*.
>
> **1775** Ash’s *New and Complete Dictionary of the English Language* observes that *compare* commonly appears with the prepositions *with* and *to*.
>
> **1818** Todd's revision of Johnson's *Dictionary of the English Language* links the "examine side by side" sense of the verb to *compare with* and the "liken" sense of the verb to *compare to*.
>
> **1828** Webster's *American Dictionary of the English Language* spreads the rule outlined by Todd to North America.

Noah Webster was a master purloiner—an inveterate user (without acknowledgment) of other lexicographers’ wordings and opinions when he deemed them sufficiently accurate to be worth appropriating. In the case of the rule governing *compared  to* and *compared with*, credit (or responsibility) for identifying the rule that subsequently appeared in Webster’s 1828 dictionary  goes to H.J. Todd, whose revision of Johnson’s dictionary appeared ten years earlier and who may owe a debt to John Ash and William Perry for having emphasized the association of *compare* with *with* and *to* in dictionaries that appeared earlier still. Todd’s 1818 dictionary may not be the original source either, but it is the earliest source that my research uncovered.